# React to message if embed includes <Insert word here>

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a piece of code that reacts to a specific bot in a channel but the piece of code reacts to everything the bot says. The bot only types out in embed messages and I wasn't sure how to make the code look inside the embedded message and react to the message only if a certain keyword is said inside of the embed.
Code:

```
client = discord.Client()
token = ("<discord token>")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = client.get_channel(825437474871312387)
    if message.channel == channel and message.author.id == 342644185800769537:
        if message.content == "test":
            await message.add_reaction("❤️")
            print("done")



if __name__ == '__main__':

    client.run(token, bot=False)
    print("can you see me?")
```

Comment: You might want to redact the token.

Comment: That is a great idea

Comment: You can get the embed of a message using `message.embed`. Here is the documentation for an [embed](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message%20embed#discord.Embed)

Comment: would it be possible to for example if the title of the embed sent was "Test" to only add a reaction to the embed with that specific title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can add reaction only to the embed with a specific title.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = client.get_channel(825437474871312387)
    if message.embeds and message.channel == channel and message.author.id == 342644185800769537:
        if message.embeds[0].title == "test":
            await message.add_reaction("❤️")
            print("done")
```

I added one more check to `if` statement (`if message.embeds`) to make sure that the message has embed inside it. Then I use `message.embeds[0]` because `message.embeds` returns a list of embeds. After that you can get information from the embed like title, author etc. ([`discord.Embed` in docs](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.Embed)).

Comment: Thank you for your help but when I send an embed with the title "test" the bot doesn't seem to pick it up because I am not getting any error messages or reactions on the embed.